# Python reassign function in external file

Tags: python, function, inheritance, scope, package

Imagine I import a function called `main_func()` from a Python package, which calls another function `called_func()` defined in the same file of the package.

Now, in my personal script, I want to call the `main_func()`. But with a small difference, when I run this `main_func()`, I want it to call my personally modified version of `called_func()`. This modified version of the function is defined in my personal script file.

How can I do this?

***Example:***

**Script from package called package/functions.py**

```
def main_func(a):
    return called_func(a)

def called_func(a):
    print(a)
```

**Personal script**

```
from package.functions import main_func

def called_func(a):
    # My personally modified function
    print(a, a)

main_func('Test ')
```

If I run my script, I get this output `Test`.

However, I would like to get `Test Test`

**Note:** I cannot modify the package files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the `import package.functions`, and then the assignment of your new definition of `called_func()` to the one in the module.

```py
import package.functions

from package.functions import main_func

def called_func(a):
    # My personally modified function
    print(a, a)

package.functions.called_func = called_func

main_func('Test ')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`monkey patch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) your function into the module

```
import package.functions


def called_func(a):
    # your modified function
    print(a, a)


package.functions.called_func = called_func
package.functions.main_func("Test ")
```

Gives

```
Test  Test
```